# The span of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So things are a bit unclear to me.
When we are talking about the span of a matrix, are we talking about the span of the columns?

Also, those the number of columns count (the span of the rows I believe)? For example, does a $3 \times 4$ matrix span $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^4$? So, are we just taking the bigger number?

Comment: I prefer the terminology, span of the image of the transformation defined by the matrix, as it more clearly explains what is meant, but it's also a lot more wordy so...

Comment: Do we talk about the "span of a matrix"? Much more common to talk about either the row space or the column space (or the range, when viewed as a linear transformation).

Answer (score 0):

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$, its span is defined as

$$\operatorname{span}(A) := \{ Ax \mid x \in \mathbb{K}^n \} \subset \mathbb{K}^m,$$

which after a few simple computations happens to be the span of the columns of $A$.

Comment: I would be very grateful if the person that downvoted me tell me why :)

Comment: I don't know where you get this definition, but the "span of a matrix" is not a commonly used term, as it is ambiguous (for example, if I am defining matrix multiplication acting on row vectors from the right, then I would want the span of the rows).

Comment: @MorganRodgers I think a matrix acting as a linear operator is usually conceived to be applied on column vectors.